# Как сверстать блок со скошенными сторонами (параллелограмм)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего сделать такие переходы между секциями?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует несколько способов сделать это.

Например, вы можете воспользоваться псеводоэлементами `before` и `after`, поиграв с их границами:

```css
.skew {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    background: #000000;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.skew::before {
    content: '';
    border-left: 440px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #000000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.skew::after {
    content: '';
    border-right: 440px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.skew h1,
.skew p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew">
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Так же можно воспользоваться свойством `transform` и функцией `skew` для псевдоэлемента `before` (или любого другого):

```css
.skew {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.skew::before {
    content: '';
    background: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    transform: skew(0, -10deg);
    z-index: -1;
}

.skew h1,
.skew p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skew">
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Удачи!